# How to align primary and secondary text horizontally and not vertically with Material-UI?

Tags: material-ui

I have this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import ArrowForwardIos from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowForwardIos';
import ListSubheader from '@material-ui/core/ListSubheader';
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import ListItemAvatar from '@material-ui/core/ListItemAvatar';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import FolderIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Folder';
import ListItemSecondaryAction from '@material-ui/core/ListItemSecondaryAction';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';

function App() {
  return (
    <ListItem>
    <ListItemAvatar>
    <Avatar>
    <FolderIcon />
    </Avatar>
    </ListItemAvatar>
    <ListItemText
    primary="Single-line item"
    secondary="Secondary text"
    />
    <ListItemSecondaryAction>
    <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete">
    <DeleteIcon />
    </IconButton>
    </ListItemSecondaryAction>
    </ListItem>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

"Single-line item" and "Secondary text" is vertically aligned, but I need align it horizontally. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Instead of left I need rendering on the right here:

[image]

https://gitlab.com/j4nos/tableitem/blob/master/src/App.js

How? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get the desired output using a few other elements and referring the material-ui documentation. here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-bose-4e26h

```
function App() {
  return (
    <ListItem>
      <ListItemAvatar>
        <Avatar>
          <FolderIcon />
        </Avatar>
      </ListItemAvatar>
      <Box
        textAlign="right"
        style={{ paddingRight: 5 }}
      >
        Single-line item
      </Box>
      <ListItemText
        secondaryTypographyProps={{ align: "left" }}
        secondary="Secondary text"
      />
      <ListItemSecondaryAction>
        <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete">
          <DeleteIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </ListItemSecondaryAction>
    </ListItem>
  );
}
```

Comment: Could I send you 20$ compensation with PayPal, I know it is not much, but still you helped a lot. :)

Comment: I am glad this could help you.

Comment: Do you have any idea about this issue here? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59026812/how-to-reduce-height-of-listsubheader-in-material-ui I could imagine a long term cooperation with you about my silly questions regarding `material-ui`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using Material-UI's built-in overrides on `ListItemText.classes.root` as seen below:

```
 <ListItem className={classes.listItem}>
   <ListItemText
     classes={{ root: classes.listItemRootOverride }}
     className={classes.listText}
     primary={`${tc('Foo')}:`}
   />
   <ListItemText
    classes={{ root: classes.listItemRootOverride }}
    secondary={bars}
   />
 </ListItem>
```

Classes in `useStyles`:

```
listItemRootOverride: {  /* this is the important one */
  flex: 'none',
  paddingRight: 4
},
listItem: {
  padding: theme.spacing(0)
},
listText: {
  color: theme.palette.common.black,
  paddingRight: theme.spacing(2)
}
```

Example output (disregard minor alignment issue):
[image: Example output:]